# Subsetting a R data.table using another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a some what same question as [Subsetting a data.table using another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685824/subsetting-a-data-table-using-another-data-table) and [Subset a data.table by matching columns of another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132917/subset-a-data-table-by-matching-columns-of-another-data-table?rq=1)

`dt` is the same.

```
dt

   id year event
1:  2 2005     1
2:  2 2006     1
3:  2 2007     1
4:  4 2008     1
5:  4 2009     1
6:  2 2005     0
7:  4 2006     0
8:  4 2007     0
9:  2 2008     0

dt <- data.table(id = c(2,2,2,4,4,2,4,4,2), year = c(2005:2009,2005:2008),
                 event = rep(1:0, times=c(5, 4)))
```

But, the `dt1` is a little bit different

```
dt1

   year performance  event
1: 2005        1000      1
2: 2006        1001      1
3: 2007        1002      1
4: 2008        1003      1
5: 2009        1004      1
6: 2005        1005      0
7: 2006        1006      0
8: 2007        1007      0
9: 2008        1008      0

dt1 <- data.table(year = c(2005:2009,2005:2008), performance = 1000:1008,
                  event = rep(1:0, times=c(5, 4)))
```

I want to split `dt1` based on `dt`'s `id` and group by event. The desired output would like to be two different data.tables:

```
dt1.sub1
   year performance  event
1: 2005        1000      1
2: 2006        1001      1
3: 2007        1002      1
4: 2005        1005      0
5: 2008        1008      0


dt1.sub2
   year performance  event
1: 2008        1003      1
2: 2009        1004      1
3: 2006        1006      0
4: 2007        1007      0
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using merge?

Comment: No, I made a mistake, everything is the same in `dt` and `dt` except `dt` has an additional `id` column. And I want to split `dt1` based on `dt`'s `id`.

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: You should edit/cleanup your question. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of 'data.tables'.

```
lst <- split(dt1, dt$id)
names(lst) <- paste0('dt1.sub', seq_along(lst))
lst
#$dt1.sub1
#   year performance event
#1: 2005        1000     1
#2: 2006        1001     1
#3: 2007        1002     1
#4: 2005        1005     0
#5: 2008        1008     0

#$dt1.sub2
#   year performance event
#1: 2008        1003     1
#2: 2009        1004     1
#3: 2006        1006     0
#4: 2007        1007     0
```

It is better to work within the `list`.  However, if it is really needed, then separate `data.table` objects can be created in the global environment with `list2env`

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[dt1, on = c('year', 'event')][, .(list(.SD)), by = id]$V1
#[[1]]
#   year event performance
#1: 2005     1        1000
#2: 2006     1        1001
#3: 2007     1        1002
#4: 2005     0        1005
#5: 2008     0        1008
#
#[[2]]
#   year event performance
#1: 2008     1        1003
#2: 2009     1        1004
#3: 2006     0        1006
#4: 2007     0        1007
```